# How to find the UST time zone from browser

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In My project I'm using an external API. I need to pass UTC time zone in request headers to get data. I tried with moment js but not worked well.

When I use this `moment.tz.guess()`, i got `"Asia/Calcutta"`
but I want like this `"UTC +5:30"`

Is any way to get time zone in this format -- `UTC±<hh>:<mm>`

Any good leads will be appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For me, it's unclear what you are asking, if you want to get UTC offset of the local timezone, you can use `moment().format('Z')`, see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the native function [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) like so :

```js
const UTCOffset = () => {
  const offset = - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  const hours = Math.floor(offset / 60)
  const minutes = offset % 60

  const sign = offset > 0 ? '+' : '-'

  return `UTC${sign}${String(hours).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}`
}

console.log(UTCOffset())
```

...or if you already use Moment as a dependency, you can use `'UTC'+Moment.format('Z')`